# Programmatically put an iOS device to sleep

Tags: ios, jailbreak, sleep-mode

I was wondering if there was a way to programmatically put an iDevice to sleep, for my jailbreak tweak. I would also like to test if iphone is on too. Is there any way (public or private API) that could do this? Even simulating the press would be cool. I know activator cydia tweak can do this, just wondering how.

Comment: You want to put it to sleep (send notification to hardware that it should go into power saving mode) or you want to lock the screen (simulating lock button press)? It's completely different things.

Comment: @creker I want to make it like u press the power button

Answer (score 1):

All methods from private `SpringBoardServices.framework`:

```
void* SBSSpringBoardServerPort();
void SBLockDevice(void*);
```

To lock device use this:

```
SBLockDevice(SBSSpringBoardServerPort());
```

Comment: Where do I download this framework? Im confused because there are different ones all over the web.

Comment: You should read about private APIs. You should know how to use the code in my answer if you're working with jailbreak.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/app111/powercode/blob/8ebd82f76d20e2b05a00697f487d249e3affd679/ios/BestPractice/BestPractice/SecondViewController.m